# Optimizing ISO String Formatting in Elixir

Tags: performance, date, time, elixir

I have two functions for formatting ISO date and ISO time strings to conventional strings, e.g. "1999-10-12" -> "12/10/1999" & "18:00:00" -> "6:00pm", and they involve a lot of conversion functions...

I wonder if there a more performant way of formatting ISO string inputs:

```
  # ISO Date String to DD/MM/YYYY
  def date_to_dd_mm_yyyy(iso_date) do
    {_, date} = Date.from_iso8601(iso_date)
    {year, month, day} = Date.to_erl(date)

    Integer.to_string(day) <> "/" <> Integer.to_string(month) <> "/" <> Integer.to_string(year)
  end

  # ISO Time String to 12 hour time
  def time_to_12hour(iso_time) do
    {:ok, new_time} = Time.from_iso8601(iso_time)
    {hour, minute, _second} = Time.to_erl(new_time)

    minute_string =
      cond do
        minute < 10 ->
          "0" <> Integer.to_string(minute)
        true ->
          Integer.to_string(minute)
      end

    hour_string =
      cond do
        hour === 0 ->
          "12"
        hour > 12 ->
          Integer.to_string(hour - 12)
        hour <= 12 ->
          Integer.to_string(hour)
      end

    meridiem =
      cond do
        hour >= 12 ->
          "pm"
        hour < 12 ->
          "am"
      end

    hour_string <> ":" <> minute_string <> meridiem
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use patter matching:

```rb
defmodule IsoToMine do
  # "1999-01-01"
  def convert(<<y::binary-size(4), "-",
                m::binary-size(2), "-",
                d::binary-size(2)>> = iso_date),
  # add {:ok, date} = Date.from_iso8601(iso_date)
  # here to blow up on wrong input
    do: Enum.join([y, d, m], "/")

  # "18:00:00"
  def convert(<<h::binary-size(2), ":",
                m::binary-size(2), ":",
                _::binary-size(2)>>) do
    {h, apm} =
      case String.to_integer(h) do
        0 -> {12, "am"}
        12 -> {12, "pm"}
        am when am < 12 -> {am, "am"}
        pm when pm > 12 -> {rem(pm, 12), "pm"}
      end

    to_string(h) <> ":" <> m <> apm
  end
end
```

Now `IsoToMine.convert/1` is omnivorous:

```rb
iex|1 ▶ IsoToMine.convert "1999-01-01"
#⇒ "1999/01/01"
iex|2 ▶ IsoToMine.convert "12:03:01"  
#⇒ "12:03pm"
iex|3 ▶ IsoToMine.convert "11:03:01"
#⇒ "11:03am"
iex|4 ▶ IsoToMine.convert "18:03:01"
#⇒ "6:03pm"
```

---

Please note, that functions above do not validate the input and would blow up with `MatchError` / `NoFunctionClause` exception on wrong input, but I just replicated *the initial* behaviour as by your code (save for yours blows up on well-formatted but impossible dates and mine happily runs.)

Adding checks and/or gracefull fallback on the wrong input is a very easy task I am leaving to you as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks Aleksei, this method of pattern matching on binary-size is new to me. V nice!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's more performant, but there is a ready-made library called [Timex](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/getting-started.html) that can do this for you:

```
iex> "1999-10-12" |> Timex.parse!("{ISOdate}") |> Timex.format!("{D}/{M}/{YYYY}")
"12/10/1999"
iex> "18:00:00" |> Timex.parse!("{ISOtime}") |> Timex.format!("{kitchen}")
"6:00PM"
```

As they say, [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization), so I would suggest measuring the speed, and try to create a more optimised version of this code only if the date parsing and formatting turns out to be the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- as of Elixir 1.8, the native Elixir DateTime/Date/Time modules have a lot of the functionality that Timex has, so I've moved away from using Timex (it is a pretty heavy dependency) and instead just use the core modules in addition to the `tzdata` package